# Почему суммарная скорость закачки двух потоков больше одного!?

Tags: сеть, скорость

Тестирую скорость интернет - качаю файл с ftp.yandex.ru, скорость закачки где то 600 кб в секунду, если качаю два файла одновременно с того же ftp, скорость скачивания каждого чуть больше 500 кб в секунду!? speedtest.net вообще показывает закачку 3 мбит, аплоад 10мбит!

Comment: Ну, по правде сказать, 600кб * 8 ~= 4,7 Мбит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто: на сервере, откуда вы качаете или же сервер (прокси, корпоративный сервер) через который идет трафик(данные), ограничивают пропускную способность одного потока.

Для чего это делается: это механизм разделения ресурсов между пользователями сети-сервера, примеры.

1. Представьте, что вы поставили на закачку "весь тырнет" с нн-го сервера и он тратит весь канал на вас. Тогда что останется другим пользователям? Правильно - ничего.
2. Вы работаете в крутой организации, которая покупает у провайдера интернет. Канал на примерно 10 Мб/с. У вашей компании 1000 сотрудников в этом офисе. Если 1 из них "сожрет" весь канал, то остальные не смогут им воспользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Может потому что стоит ограничение скорости на скачивание в один поток? Два потока - скорость умножается? Ну, не на два, а где-то на полтора.

Comment: А какой в этом смысл?!

Comment: А очень простой. Скорость сервера - X МБит. Ее нельзя в принципе отдать на одного клиента. Т.к. остальным не достанется. Как можно поступить? Ну, или делить X/<текущее кол-во клиентов>, или просто зарезать по верхней границе скорость для каждого потока от каждого клиента.

Comment: А ну так это со стороны сервака, а если я качаю с другого, то тоже самое!

Comment: Это дело рук провайдера.

Comment: А вы откуда, и что за провайдер, если не секрет?

Comment: Ростов-на-Дону, Билайн проводной интернет!